# ZEND application not quite runnig while fresh SVN checkout 

Tags: zend-framework, exception

There's nothing I can say really, as I'm not into ZEND... All I can say is I get a stack of errors/warnings that look like :

```
Zend_Exception: No entry is registered for key 'liveHeader' in /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Registry.php on line 147 Call Stack: 0.0007 630840 1. {main}() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/public/index.php:0 0.2304 4603280 2. Zend_Application->run() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/public/index.php:42 0.2304 4603280 3. Bootstrap->run() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Application.php:328 0.2346 4626200 4. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/application/Bootstrap.php:12 0.2348 4626520 5. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch($request = ???, $response = ???) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php:77 1.6190 13445472 6. Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->postDispatch($request = class Zend_Controller_Request_Http { protected $_paramSources = array (0 => '_GET', 1 => '_POST'); protected $_requestUri = '/'; protected $_baseUrl = ''; protected $_basePath = NULL; protected $_pathInfo = '/'; protected $_params = array ('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'); protected $_aliases = array (); protected $_dispatched = TRUE; protected $_module = 'default'; protected $_moduleKey = 'module'; protected $_controller = 'index'; protected $_controllerKey = 'controller'; protected $_action = 'index'; protected $_actionKey = 'action' }) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php:956 1.6191 13445472 7. Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout->postDispatch($request = class Zend_Controller_Request_Http { protected $_paramSources = array (0 => '_GET', 1 => '_POST'); protected $_requestUri = '/'; protected $_baseUrl = ''; protected $_basePath = NULL; protected $_pathInfo = '/'; protected $_params = array ('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'); protected $_aliases = array (); protected $_dispatched = TRUE; protected $_module = 'default'; protected $_moduleKey = 'module'; protected $_controller = 'index'; protected $_controllerKey = 'controller'; protected $_action = 'index'; protected $_actionKey = 'action' }) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php:330 1.6193 13445976 8. Zend_Layout->render($name = ???) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Layout/Controller/Plugin/Layout.php:142 1.6203 13450944 9. Zend_View_Abstract->render($name = 'layout.phtml') /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Layout.php:791 1.6204 13492584 10. Zend_View->_run('/Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/application/views/scripts/layout.phtml') /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:832 1.6215 13653240 11. include('/Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/application/views/scripts/layout.phtml') /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/View.php:107 1.7286 15289440 12. YPush->LayoutTop() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/application/views/scripts/layout.phtml:153 1.7286 15289704 13. YPush->__call($method = 'LayoutTop', $attr = array ()) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush.php:153 1.7295 15336024 14. YPush->getData() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush.php:79 1.7295 15336024 15. YPush->loadData() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush.php:122 1.7295 15336544 16. call_user_func_array(array (0 => class YPush_LayoutTop { private ${YPush}:_file = 'layouttop.php'; protected $_dir = ''; protected $_class = 'YPush'; protected $_attr = array (...); protected $_cache = FALSE; protected $_lifetime = 86400; private ${YPush}:_id = 'LayoutTop_2723407904'; public $request = class Zend_Controller_Request_Http { ... }; private ${Zend_View}:_useViewStream = FALSE; private ${Zend_View}:_useStreamWrapper = FALSE; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_path = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_file = NULL; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_helper = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_helperLoaded = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_helperLoadedDir = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_filter = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_filterClass = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_filterLoaded = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_filterLoadedDir = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_escape = 'htmlspecialchars'; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_lfiProtectionOn = TRUE; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_loaders = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_loaderTypes = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_strictVars = FALSE; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_log = NULL }, 1 => 'prepare'), array ()) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush.php:132 1.7295 15336792 17. YPush_LayoutTop->prepare() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush.php:132 1.7295 15336872 18. Zend_Registry::get($index = 'liveHeader') /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush/LayoutTop.php:15 Variables in local scope (#18): $index = 'liveHeader' $instance = class Zend_Registry { public $Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry = class Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry { protected $_containerClass = 'Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container'; protected $_items = array (...) }; public $db = class Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql { protected $_pdoType = 'mysql'; protected $_numericDataTypes = array (...); protected $_defaultStmtClass = 'Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo'; protected $_config = array (...); protected $_fetchMode = 2; protected $_profiler = class Zend_Db_Profiler { ... }; protected $_defaultProfilerClass = 'Zend_Db_Profiler'; protected $_connection = class PDO { ... }; protected $_caseFolding = 0; protected $_autoQuoteIdentifiers = TRUE; protected $_allowSerialization = TRUE; protected $_autoReconnectOnUnserialize = FALSE }; public $db_master = class Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql { protected $_pdoType = 'mysql'; protected $_numericDataTypes = array (...); protected $_defaultStmtClass = 'Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo'; protected $_config = array (...); protected $_fetchMode = 2; protected $_profiler = class Zend_Db_Profiler { ... }; protected $_defaultProfilerClass = 'Zend_Db_Profiler'; protected $_connection = class PDO { ... }; protected $_caseFolding = 0; protected $_autoQuoteIdentifiers = TRUE; protected $_allowSerialization = TRUE; protected $_autoReconnectOnUnserialize = FALSE }; public $Zend_Locale = class Zend_Locale { protected $_locale = 'fr' }; public $WideLocale = 'fr_FR'; public $UrlTranslator = class Zend_Translate { private $_adapter = class Zend_Translate_Adapter_Csv { ... } }; public $config = class Zend_Config_Ini { protected $_nestSeparator = '.'; protected $_sectionSeparator = ':'; protected $_skipExtends = FALSE; protected $_allowModifications = FALSE; protected $_index = 0; protected $_count = 8; protected $_data = array (...); protected $_skipNextIteration = NULL; protected $_loadedSection = array (...); protected $_extends = array (...); protected $_loadFileErrorStr = NULL }; public $Zend_View_Helper_Doctype = class ArrayObject { public $doctypes = array (...); public $doctype = 'HTML4_LOOSE' } } Zend_Exception: No entry is registered for key 'liveLogo' in /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Registry.php on line 147 Call Stack: 0.0007 630840 1. {main}() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/public/index.php:0 0.2304 4603280 2. Zend_Application->run() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/public/index.php:42 0.2304 4603280 3. Bootstrap->run() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Application.php:328 0.2346 4626200 4. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/application/Bootstrap.php:12 0.2348 4626520 5. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch($request = ???, $response = ???) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php:77 1.6190 13445472 6. Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->postDispatch($request = class Zend_Controller_Request_Http { protected $_paramSources = array (0 => '_GET', 1 => '_POST'); protected $_requestUri = '/'; protected $_baseUrl = ''; protected $_basePath = NULL; protected $_pathInfo = '/'; protected $_params = array ('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'); protected $_aliases = array (); protected $_dispatched = TRUE; protected $_module = 'default'; protected $_moduleKey = 'module'; protected $_controller = 'index'; protected $_controllerKey = 'controller'; protected $_action = 'index'; protected $_actionKey = 'action' }) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php:956 1.6191 13445472 7. Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout->postDispatch($request = class Zend_Controller_Request_Http { protected $_paramSources = array (0 => '_GET', 1 => '_POST'); protected $_requestUri = '/'; protected $_baseUrl = ''; protected $_basePath = NULL; protected $_pathInfo = '/'; protected $_params = array ('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'); protected $_aliases = array (); protected $_dispatched = TRUE; protected $_module = 'default'; protected $_moduleKey = 'module'; protected $_controller = 'index'; protected $_controllerKey = 'controller'; protected $_action = 'index'; protected $_actionKey = 'action' }) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php:330 1.6193 13445976 8. Zend_Layout->render($name = ???) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Layout/Controller/Plugin/Layout.php:142 1.6203 13450944 9. Zend_View_Abstract->render($name = 'layout.phtml') /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/Layout.php:791 1.6204 13492584 10. Zend_View->_run('/Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/application/views/scripts/layout.phtml') /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:832 1.6215 13653240 11. include('/Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/application/views/scripts/layout.phtml') /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/ZF/library/Zend/View.php:107 1.7286 15289440 12. YPush->LayoutTop() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/application/views/scripts/layout.phtml:153 1.7286 15289704 13. YPush->__call($method = 'LayoutTop', $attr = array ()) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush.php:153 1.7295 15336024 14. YPush->getData() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush.php:79 1.7295 15336024 15. YPush->loadData() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush.php:122 1.7295 15336544 16. call_user_func_array(array (0 => class YPush_LayoutTop { private ${YPush}:_file = 'layouttop.php'; protected $_dir = ''; protected $_class = 'YPush'; protected $_attr = array (...); protected $_cache = FALSE; protected $_lifetime = 86400; private ${YPush}:_id = 'LayoutTop_2723407904'; public $request = class Zend_Controller_Request_Http { ... }; private ${Zend_View}:_useViewStream = FALSE; private ${Zend_View}:_useStreamWrapper = FALSE; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_path = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_file = NULL; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_helper = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_helperLoaded = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_helperLoadedDir = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_filter = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_filterClass = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_filterLoaded = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_filterLoadedDir = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_escape = 'htmlspecialchars'; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_lfiProtectionOn = TRUE; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_loaders = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_loaderTypes = array (...); private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_strictVars = FALSE; private ${Zend_View_Abstract}:_log = NULL }, 1 => 'prepare'), array ()) /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush.php:132 1.7295 15336792 17. YPush_LayoutTop->prepare() /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush.php:132 1.7307 15371992 18. Zend_Registry::get($index = 'liveLogo') /Users/koopa/Sites/ykone/trunk/library/YPush/LayoutTop.php:21 Variables in local scope (#18): $index = 'liveLogo' $instance = class Zend_Registry { public $Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry = class Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry { protected $_containerClass = 'Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container'; protected $_items = array (...) }; public $db = class Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql { protected $_pdoType = 'mysql'; protected $_numericDataTypes = array (...); protected $_defaultStmtClass = 'Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo'; protected $_config = array (...); protected $_fetchMode = 2; protected $_profiler = class Zend_Db_Profiler { ... }; protected $_defaultProfilerClass = 'Zend_Db_Profiler'; protected $_connection = class PDO { ... }; protected $_caseFolding = 0; protected $_autoQuoteIdentifiers = TRUE; protected $_allowSerialization = TRUE; protected $_autoReconnectOnUnserialize = FALSE }; public $db_master = class Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql { protected $_pdoType = 'mysql'; protected $_numericDataTypes = array (...); protected $_defaultStmtClass = 'Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo'; protected $_config = array (...); protected $_fetchMode = 2; protected $_profiler = class Zend_Db_Profiler { ... }; protected $_defaultProfilerClass = 'Zend_Db_Profiler'; protected $_connection = class PDO { ... }; protected $_caseFolding = 0; protected $_autoQuoteIdentifiers = TRUE; protected $_allowSerialization = TRUE; protected $_autoReconnectOnUnserialize = FALSE }; public $Zend_Locale = class Zend_Locale { protected $_locale = 'fr' }; public $WideLocale = 'fr_FR'; public $UrlTranslator = class Zend_Translate { private $_adapter = class Zend_Translate_Adapter_Csv { ... } }; public $config = class Zend_Config_Ini { protected $_nestSeparator = '.'; protected $_sectionSeparator = ':'; protected $_skipExtends = FALSE; protected $_allowModifications = FALSE; protected $_index = 0; protected $_count = 8; protected $_data = array (...); protected $_skipNextIteration = NULL; protected $_loadedSection = array (...); protected $_extends = array (...); protected $_loadFileErrorStr = NULL }; public $Zend_View_Helper_Doctype = class ArrayObject { public $doctypes = array (...); public $doctype = 'HTML4_LOOSE' } }
```

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You call `Zend_Registry::get('liveHeader')` before `Zend_Registry::set('liveHeader', $liveHeader)` which is wrong. `Zend_Registry` is a global singelton which behaves much like an array, similar to a plain php variant:

```
$liveHeader = ....
$registry = array('liveHeader' => $liveHeader);
```

Comment: But... I can't explain to myself how this exact application runs perfectly on my Imac, using MAMP, and not on my macbook, running native php,mysql, and apache. Could this explain that ?

Comment: Aren't you using auto_preppend_file or something like that?

Comment: Where could I check for this (when I said I was not into ZEND, I meant, really not ;p)

Comment: @pixelboy: search through both your working environment, and the newly  checked out environment for the string `Zend_Registry::set('liveHeader'`. It should be **missing** from the newly checked out one.

Comment: If the app works on your iMac but not your MacBook, it's probably differences in your php.ini files. Compare the 2 files to see what's different.